# Is there a plugin to show the pages that link to a certain document?

Tags: modx

Does anyone know of a plugin for modx that will show all the pages that link to each document ID or would I have to create my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a snippet for yourself. Use the code

`$weblinkArray = $modx->getCollection('modWeblink',$criteria);`

where `$criteria` is the set of criteria, restrictions or constraints you want to set, like

`$criteria = array(
    'published' => 1,// this is optional, more parameters can be optionally added as well
)`

This gives you an array of the documents that link. Further, you know how to access data of an array.